# WordPress Custom Taxonomy with Custom Query Pagination Not Working - 404 Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having trouble getting pagination working for custom taxonomy archive with the custom query. The pagination on the taxonomy archive ends up with a 404 page.

I have to run a query multiple times on many areas, so I have created a method for that.

## Query Method

```
/**
 * @param bool  $post_type
 * @param bool  $posts_per_page
 * @param bool  $paged
 * @param array $extra_args
 *
 * @return \WP_Query
 */
public function module_query( $post_type = FALSE, $posts_per_page = FALSE, $paged = FALSE, array $extra_args = [] ) {
    // basic arguments
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => $post_type ? $post_type : self::get_module_cpt(),
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page ? $posts_per_page : - 1,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    ];

    // set paged
    if ( $paged ) {
        $args[ 'paged' ] = $paged;
    }

    $args = wp_parse_args( $extra_args, $args );

    // init meta query var
    $meta_query   = [];
    $meta_query[] = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_roles',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_users',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ],
    ];
    $meta_query[] = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_roles',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_users',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
        ],
    ];

    // init permit roles var
    $permit_roles = [];
    $r            = 0;

    // loop through each roles and prepare array for meta query
    foreach ( $this->get_current_user_roles() as $current_user_role ) {
        $permit_roles[ $r ][ 'key' ]     = 'permit_roles';
        $permit_roles[ $r ][ 'value' ]   = sprintf( ':"%s";', $current_user_role );
        $permit_roles[ $r ][ 'compare' ] = 'LIKE';

        $r ++;
    }

    $meta_query[] = [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        $permit_roles,
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_users',
            'value'   => sprintf( ':"%s";', get_current_user_id() ),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
    ];

    // add meta query relation if more than one query
    if ( count( $meta_query ) > 1 ) {
        $meta_query[ 'relation' ] = 'OR';
    }

    // add meta query only for non admin users
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        $args[ 'meta_query' ] = $meta_query;
    }

    // return the query object
    return new WP_Query( $args );
}
```

## taxonomy.php Query

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$the_query = $cp->module_query(
    $cp::get_resource_cpt(), cp_get_addons_per_page(), $paged,
    [
        'orderby'   => 'publish_date',
        'tax_query' => [
            'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ $term->slug ],
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ],
    ]
);

...
// while loop
...

// pagination
$cp->bootstrap_pagination( $the_query );

// reset query
wp_reset_postdata();
```

## Pagination function

> The pagination is working fine on the Custom Post time page with a
> custom loop.

```
function bootstrap_pagination( \WP_Query $wp_query = NULL, $echo = TRUE ) {

    if ( NULL === $wp_query ) {
        global $wp_query;
    }

    $pages = paginate_links( [
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'type'         => 'array',
            'show_all'     => FALSE,
            'end_size'     => 3,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => TRUE,
            'prev_text'    => __( '« Prev' ),
            'next_text'    => __( 'Next »' ),
            'add_args'     => FALSE,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ]
    );

    if ( is_array( $pages ) ) {

        $pagination = '<div class="row"><div class="col mt-5"><div class="pagination d-flex justify-content-center"><ul class="pagination pagination-sm">';

        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            $pagination .= '<li class="page-item' . ( strpos( $page, 'current' ) !== FALSE ? ' active' : '' ) . '"> ' . str_replace( 'page-numbers', 'page-link', $page ) . '</li>';
        }

        $pagination .= '</ul></div></div></div><!-- end pagination -->';

        if ( $echo ) {
            echo $pagination;
        } else {
            return $pagination;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Have you saved your permalinks and flushed your rewrite rules?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes, I did many times and every time after updating a single line of code. So I believe the issue is something else.